# draw string on CGContext buffer and pick texture data, but the data never changed, why?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, drawstring

In the cocos2d I can not use some method like `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` so i do it like that way following this:

```
memset(textData, 0, sW*sH*4);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(textData, sW, sH, 8, sW*4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 1, 1, 1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, sH);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);

UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

NSString* sstr = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char*)str encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];//its right
UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:12];

[sstr drawInRect:CGRectMake(x, sH-y,100,100) withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];

UIGraphicsPopContext();

CGContextRelease(context);
```

When I debug and breakpoint at `UIGraphicsPopContext`, the content of `textData` is always zero in the memory view, somebody help me. `context` and `textData` is not nil.